# asp.net core api PUT request never hits method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, put

I am attempting to create a web api in asp.net. I am trying to use ajax to send my query parameters to the action method, but it never reaches it. FYI I am not well experienced with ajax.

I am trying to use a form in my view to pass the data to the action method but it does nothing. Here is my view:

```
<form action="/api/values" method="put">
    <ul>
        <li>
           <input type="text" id="Id" />
        </li>
        <li>
           <input type="text" id="FirstName" />
        </li>
        <li>
           <button onclick="Update()" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Here is my ajax:

```
<script>
    function Update(Id, FirstName) {
       $.ajax({
           url: "/api/values/" + Id + "/" + FirstName,
           type: "PUT",
           data: {
             Id: Id,
             FirstName: FirstName
           },
           success: function () {
              alert("success");
           }
       )};
    }
</script>
```

My url will look like: `/api/values?Id=123XXXjxn&FirstName=Billy`

This never reaches my controller:

```
[HttpPut("{Id}/{FirstName}")]
public ActionResult PutRequest([FromQuery] string Id, [FromQuery] string FirstName)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

I have tried it with just the `[HttpPut]` attribute, and used the `[Route("{Id}/{FirstName}")]` attribute, and without `[FromQuery]` in the parameters. I am stuck and am thinking it has to do with my ajax, and my method not being able to read the query parameters but I am not totally sure.

Comment: I don't see where *api* prefix should come from (controller?) and *values*

Comment: And why do you have query parameters here `/api/values?Id=123XXXjxn&FirstName=Billy` and path here `/api/values/" + Id + "/" + FirstName,`

Comment: Yes I am assuming either my ajax or my query is completely wrong, how should I fix it, maybe like this `/api/values?Id={Id}&FirstName={FirstName}` in my ajax?

Comment: My url looks like that whenever I fill out the form and hit Update

Comment: It automatically adds the `?` and `&` but I want the url to be `/api/values/123XXXxxx/Billy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look like that

Controller

```
[Route("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPut("{Id}/{FirstName}")]
    public ActionResult PutRequest(string Id, string FirstName)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

View

```
<script>
    function Update(Id, FirstName) {
       $.ajax({
           url: "/api/values/" + Id + "/" + FirstName,
           type: "PUT",
           success: function () {
              alert("success");
           }
       });
    }
</script>
```

Since you do ajax call, you don't need form attributes, prevent navigating to url with `event.preventDefault()`

```
<script>
    function Update(Id, FirstName) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/values/" + Id + "/" + FirstName,
            type: "PUT",
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="Id" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="FirstName" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" onclick="Update()" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And, of course, you need some version of jquery. You can get latest [here](https://code.jquery.com/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This is what I now have. When I fill out my form I end up with this url `api/values?Id=123xxxx&FirstName=namexxxx`, even when I type in `api/values/123kdfj/namexxx` into the address bar, I end up with a 405 error. Is it possible that because my api class has a constructor with my dbcontext that is my method is never reached?

Comment: added fix for a form, so it does not navigate.you can't access this url from address bard since browsers send only GET requests from there

Comment: constructor does not matter, it is part of Dependency Injection pattern

Comment: I have no idea, I am trying, I have breakpoints which never get hit and my ajax and action are never hit for some reason. I will have to keep trying but thanks for the help.

Comment: show your controller and console/ network tab output

Comment: I see now under Sources tab that `$.ajax` is getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I'm assuming that I will need some js reference file.

Comment: @stupidQuestions , `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` , sounds like you haven't included the jQuery library.

Comment: Yeah I've never had to do that. I tried `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"` but I could'nt get it to work, I'll have to do some reading @JonP

Comment: I will accept this answer, just add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"` to the top. This is so annoying that is all I needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller code should look like that

```
[Route("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/api/values/{Id}/{FirstName}")]
    public ActionResult PutRequest(string Id, string FirstName)
    {
       .......
    }
}
Your url shood look like: /api/values/123XXXjxn/Billy
```

Change in javascript

```
type: "PUT",
data: {

             Id: Id,
             FirstName: FirstName
           },
```

To

```
type: "POST",
data: null,
```

and check if you have   app.UseRouting(); in Configure section of your startup file.

Comment: Yes, when I fill out the form and hit update my url is `?Id=123xxxjxn?FirstName=Billy`, how can I correct that?

Comment: [`[FromQuery]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) denotes that the parameters should be bound using the request query string, not path paremeters.

Comment: I did all of this, I even typed in the url `/api/values/123xxxxxx/Billy` into my address bar and just receive a 405 error. I am not sure how to make ajax generate this url automatically instead of the url with `?` and `&`

Comment: Remove [PUT] from your controller action and maybe try to change To [POST] in you ajax